# Task.Run(() => Method()); doesn't run the method?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, task

In my WPF application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CloudKey
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AuthText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AuthText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        await Task.Run(() => Authenticate());
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Authenticate());
        Task.Run(() => Authenticate());
        Authenticate();
    }
    void Authenticate()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
  }
}
```

No matter which way I try to call `Authenticate` with `Tasks` it just doesn't run. Am I using `Task` wrong?

Using await (and async) causes an exception to be thrown:

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Using just Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew causes the Authenticate method not to be run at all.  If I add a breakpoint to the Authenticate method it isn't reached.

Just calling the method with Authenticate() runs the entire method without issue, but it freezes the UI making "AuthText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;" useless.

To be honest, I really just want the UI to update with the message "Authenticating..." and THEN run everything in the method when I click the button. Is there perhaps an easier way to do that?

THIS IS THE WORKING CODE FOR REFERENCE:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CloudKey
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //private void PasswordBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { button_Click } }
        AuthText.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //ON CONTINUE BUTTON CLICK
    {
        AuthText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Task.Run(() => Authenticate());
    }
    void Authenticate()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
        () =>
        {
          //ALL MY CODE HERE;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Authenticate()); should definately work - although calling any UI stuff in there can make weird things happen

Comment: What does `Authenticate` do?  Might it be throwing an exception on a non UI thread that's being swallowed?

Comment: How do you know nothing happens? Define nothing happens? If you breakpoint the method is it reached?

Comment: Task.Run starts a new thread that performs that task as does StartNew, because this is a new thread you can't guarantee that it is running before or after what ever check you are depending on, try adding the await key work this will instruct your code to wait for the completion of the task before continuing

Comment: His code probably stops before it even finishes, had this happening to me once aswell, felt dumb as hell. @MikeT

Comment: I do grab some input from text boxes in the UI.
If I breakpoint the method it is NOT reached.
If I add await (and async to button_Click) I get an exception thrown: 

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Added more info to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify UI stuff in a new thread then you need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or you can use `InvokeAsync`

```
    private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) { Task.Run( () => Authenticate() ); }

    public void Authenticate()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            () =>
            {
                ClickButton.Content = "Text Changed";
            } );
    }
```

By using `Dispatcher` You are telling WPF that run this code block on main thread which has access to update your GUI controls.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!  I did this:

private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) { Task.Run( () => Authenticate() ); }

    public void Authenticate()
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            () =>
            {
                My entire code here;
            } );
    }

and it works!

Comment: Hey Adeel,  I have a new animation I'd like to run while some code runs in the background.  The question is located [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150529/why-is-my-asynchronous-task-freezing-ai-animations-in-the-gui?noredirect=1#comment61841770_37150529) if you'd like to help!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're not waiting for the asynchronous task to complete, so it appears like "nothing happens" - when in fact something does happen. When you invoke either `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` you're essentially performaing a fire-and-forget, unless you correctly handle the `Task`.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Authenticate()); // Stuff happens
}

void Authenticate()
{
    // DO STUFF
}
```

In the example above adding the keyword `async` to the event handler allows the method to utilize the `await` keyword. The `await` keyword is where all the magic really occurs...but it will then work as you'd expect, i.e.; "Stuff happens".

When I do beat Stephen Cleary to these answers I usually point people to his blogs, [this one](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) in particular should help clarify this for you.

**Note**

Writing an `async void` is strongly discouraged! The only exception is in your example where you are applying it to an event handler. Finally, when using `Task`, and `Task<T>` with the `async / await` keywords - do so through the entire stack. I would change your `Authenticate` method to return a `Task` for example, such that it can be awaited. Try invoking `Task.Run` at the lowest level possible.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Authenticate(); // Stuff happens
}

Task Authenticate()
{
    return _authModule.Authenticate();
}
```

**Update**

Based on your comments, do the following:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool authenticated = false;
    try
    {
        AuthText = "Authenticating...";
        authenticated = Authenticate(); // Stuff happens
    }
    finally
    {
        AuthText = authenticated ? "Authenticated" : "Oops!";
    }
}

bool Authenticate()
{
    // Return if auth was successful
}
```

Comment: After changing my code to reflect yours I get an error: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Added more info to the original post.

Comment: If you have any UI elements you are interacting with you'll need to marshal back to the UI thread.

Comment: To be honest, I really just want the UI to update with the message "Authenticating..." and THEN run everything in the method when I click the button. Is there perhaps an easier way to do that?

Comment: Hey, the answer provided by adeel41 ended up working.  Thanks for all your help though, I really appreciate it!  I would upvote you, but I only have 14pts / 15 required. xD

Comment: Hey David,  I have a new animation I'd like to run while some code runs in the background.  The question is located [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150529/why-is-my-asynchronous-task-freezing-ai-animations-in-the-gui?noredirect=1#comment61841770_37150529) if you'd like to help!