# Why is my asynchronous task freezing AI animations in the GUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, asynchronous, dispatcher

My code looks pretty much like the following:

```
namespace CloudKey
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Begin Loading animation
        Loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        //Run Task
        await Task.Run(() => LoginCheck());
    }

    async void LoginCheck()
    {
        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
                () =>
                {
                    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
                    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
                    ss.AppendLine("some code here")
                    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
                    {
                        Collection<PSObject> results = null;
                        try
                        {
                            runspace.Open();
                            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(ss.ToString());
                            results = pipeline.Invoke();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            runspace.Close();
                            Loading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                            if //some stuff
                            {
                                //do some things
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //do some other things
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
  }
}
```

I've also tried

```
Async void LoginCheck()
{
    await Dispatcher.Invoke (() => {//Stuff});
}
```

with the same result.  I'm not actually sure what the difference between the two are...

The task runs correctly either way, but the animation starts then freezes as soon as the task begins. :/  What should I do to make this work the way I intend it to with the loading animation animating throughout the functions?

EDIT:

I should add that I attempted to remove the

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
            () =>{});
```

and leave the rest of the function in tact, however, I get the following error when I do so:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Comment: You're telling a new thread pool thread to do nothing but tell the UI thread to execute a bunch of code.  That all of the code is thus run in the UI thread is to be expected.  You need to actually run code outside of the UI thread if you want to run code outside of the UI thread.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...Could you give an example?

Comment: *You* provided an example of it.  You're running all of your code in the UI thread and complaining that all of your code is running in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all that's needed is to remove the

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { };
```

surrounding the code. Looking at the Documentation for Dispatcher.InvokeAsync, it says "Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with." ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync(v=vs.110).aspx)) The Dispatcher linked to a page is associated with the page's thread, so it's executing the code on the UI thread, still. Removing that surrounding function call should make the code simply run on a different thread because you already called Task.Run() to run it on a different thread.

EDIT: Missed the part where Loading got changed, which is owned by the UI thread. Here's an actual code sample that illustrates the issue better:

```
async void LoginCheck()
{
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
    ss.AppendLine("some code here")
    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
    {
        Collection<PSObject> results = null;
        try
        {
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(ss.ToString());
            results = pipeline.Invoke();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            runspace.Close();
            Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {
                Loading.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            });

            if //some stuff
            {
                //do some things
            }
            else
            {
                //do some other things
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because Loading.Visibility is a UI Element, it's owned by the UI thread. So surrounding just that call with Dispatcher.Invoke() will change that value from the UI Thread, while still executing the db calls on the other thread as explained above.

Comment: I get an error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @NickG I found the issue and edited the answer accordingly. Didn't notice that Loading.Visibility call.

Comment: After debugging it was because I called a UI function from that working thread.  Your suggestion worked!

Comment: Nice, glad it worked. I remember having some issues with these things when I was new to WPF too.